# Сообщения как в вк

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Надо, что бы выводило от im из ссылки ($_GET[im]), то есть ссылка такая сайт.ру?im=1 и надо чтобы по этой цифре (вывод её такой $_GET[im]) искало в таблице по im и senderID, а потом все это выводило.
Это как в вк, в ссылке обозначен id переписки, мне надо вывести сообщения в которых совпадают эти числа и выводяться сообщения с senderID и im

Примерный скрипт вывода, он не работает. выводит только сообщения которые я должен получить:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE im='$_GET[im]' ORDER BY id DESC") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
   if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
    echo "У вас нет диологов с данным пользователем.";
    while ($mess = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "Вывод";
        }
      }
      ?>
```

Дамп базы:

```
      CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipient` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mess` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `times` datetime NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `im` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `senderID` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE im='$_GET[im]' AND senderID='$_GET[im]' ORDER BY id DESC")
```

Это если я вас правильно понял) а вообще НИКОГДА! НИКОГДА не обращайтесь к БД через переменные GET и POST сначала сохраняйте их в другую локальную, фильтруйте её, и только потом запрос. (иначе SQL инъекции передадут вам привет)

P.S. если не правильно понял суть вопроса. уточните

Comment: Не правильно. Теперь пишет, что нету не чего

Comment: Да ладно. Я разобрался уже. построил новую систему. Вам +, все таки ответ правильный так то, но почему только не работает.